# How to track the user behavior and personalization on mobile Apps using Xamarin Sitecore SDK?

Tags: sitecore-api, xconnect

I need to provide the personalized content to the mobile apps through SSC/Sitecore mobile SDK and track the user behavior and capture in the xDB.

As per my understanding, "Sitecore Mobile SDK currently does not support xDB integration for tracking actions in the mobile app or mobile content personalization out of the box"

But with Sitecore 9 release, The Sitecore Services Client (SSC) API is capable to provide personalized content to the mobile apps and tracking the behavior on the mobile Apps.

Can we achieve this requirement through xConnect.

I am not sure how to do the rule based Personalization(changed the presentation details) on mobile apps.

Is there any documentation and references available for this implementation?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing issue related to this. I need to enable personalization through presentation component by setting up some rules. Do I need to have xconnect installed. I have plain sitcore 9 instance with solr. I am new to this. If xconnect is needed then how can I update my existing sitcore 9 instance with SIF-install.ps1 with xconnect.
Thanks!!

Comment: I am Sure xConnect is the only way to achieve this functionality, but not done practically yet..

Comment: Sitecore JSS with React Native could be alternative approach: https://jss.sitecore.net/#/react-native?id=sitecore-jss-react-native

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and Now I am able to set the rules and personalize the content as per devices and many other options without xConnect.

There was an issue in sitecore 9 installation and there is a hotfix by sitecore to fix the issue and below is the link to that:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/828414

Thanks
Anuj Chawla

Comment: can you please provide the more information